# Update Manager Ubuntu 12.10 (1) Failed to fetch cdrom: (2) Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonls/

Tags: 12.10, update-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I fix a 404 Error using a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-a-ppa)

Please guide how to solve problem described below:

**ERROR received while running Update Manager in UBUNTU 12.10:**

```
W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 11.10 _Oneiric Ocelot_ - Release i386 (20111012)/dists/oneiric/main/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
, W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 11.10 _Oneiric Ocelot_ - Release i386 (20111012)/dists/oneiric/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonls/redshift-ppa/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonls/redshift-ppa/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

**Copy from TERMINAL when run sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade:**

```
nnnnnnnnnn:~$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
[sudo] password for neeta: 
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 11.10 _Oneiric Ocelot_ - Release i386 (20111012) oneiric InRelease
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 11.10 _Oneiric Ocelot_ - Release i386 (20111012) oneiric Release.gpg
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 11.10 _Oneiric Ocelot_ - Release i386 (20111012) oneiric Release
Err cdrom://Ubuntu 11.10 _Oneiric Ocelot_ - Release i386 (20111012) oneiric/main i386 Packages
  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Err cdrom://Ubuntu 11.10 _Oneiric Ocelot_ - Release i386 (20111012) oneiric/restricted i386 Packages
  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 11.10 _Oneiric Ocelot_ - Release i386 (20111012) oneiric/main Translation-en_IN
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 11.10 _Oneiric Ocelot_ - Release i386 (20111012) oneiric/main Translation-en
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 11.10 _Oneiric Ocelot_ - Release i386 (20111012) oneiric/restricted Translation-en_IN
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 11.10 _Oneiric Ocelot_ - Release i386 (20111012) oneiric/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                      
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com quantal InRelease                             
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security InRelease                      
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com oneiric InRelease                                 
Ign http://deb.opera.com stable InRelease                                      
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                    
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates InRelease                     
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security Release.gpg                    
Ign http://archive.canonical.com oneiric InRelease                             
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal InRelease                                 
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com oneiric Release.gpg                               
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                                        
Ign http://deb.opera.com stable InRelease                                      
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports InRelease                   
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security Release                        
Ign http://archive.canonical.com quantal InRelease                             
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty InRelease                                   
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com oneiric Release                                   
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages                             
Hit http://deb.opera.com stable Release.gpg                                    
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com quantal Release.gpg                           
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main Sources                   
Hit http://archive.canonical.com oneiric Release.gpg                           
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release.gpg                               
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com oneiric/main Sources                              
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates Release.gpg                   
Hit http://deb.opera.com stable Release.gpg                                    
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/restricted Sources             
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty Release.gpg                                 
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com oneiric/main i386 Packages                        
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports Release.gpg                 
Hit http://deb.opera.com stable Release                                        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/universe Sources               
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release                                   
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com quantal Release                               
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/multiverse Sources             
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty Release                                     
Hit http://deb.opera.com stable Release                                        
Hit http://archive.canonical.com quantal Release.gpg                           
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates Release                       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main i386 Packages             
Hit http://deb.opera.com stable/non-free i386 Packages                         
Hit http://archive.canonical.com oneiric Release                               
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports Release                     
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/restricted i386 Packages       
Hit http://archive.canonical.com quantal Release                               
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main Sources                          
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/universe i386 Packages         
Hit http://archive.canonical.com oneiric/partner Sources                       
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/restricted Sources                    
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/multiverse i386 Packages       
Hit http://archive.canonical.com oneiric/partner i386 Packages                 
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe Sources                      
Hit http://deb.opera.com stable/non-free i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main Sources                                
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_IN                         
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/multiverse Sources                    
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main Translation-en            
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main i386 Packages                          
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                            
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main i386 Packages                    
Hit http://archive.canonical.com quantal/partner i386 Packages                 
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/restricted i386 Packages              
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com oneiric/main Translation-en_IN                    
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/multiverse Translation-en      
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe i386 Packages                
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com oneiric/main Translation-en                       
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/multiverse i386 Packages              
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/restricted Translation-en      
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main Translation-en                   
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/universe Translation-en        
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/multiverse Translation-en             
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/restricted Translation-en             
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe Translation-en               
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main Sources                  
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/restricted Sources            
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe Sources              
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/multiverse Sources            
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main i386 Packages            
Ign http://archive.canonical.com oneiric/partner Translation-en_IN             
Ign http://deb.opera.com stable/non-free Translation-en_IN                     
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/restricted i386 Packages      
Ign http://archive.canonical.com oneiric/partner Translation-en                
Ign http://deb.opera.com stable/non-free Translation-en                        
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe i386 Packages        
Ign http://archive.canonical.com quantal/partner Translation-en_IN             
Ign http://deb.opera.com stable/non-free Translation-en_IN                     
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main Translation-en_IN         
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/multiverse i386 Packages      
Ign http://archive.canonical.com quantal/partner Translation-en                
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/multiverse Translation-en_IN   
Ign http://deb.opera.com stable/non-free Translation-en                        
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/restricted Translation-en_IN
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main Sources                    
  404  Not Found
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/universe Translation-en_IN
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main Translation-en_IN
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main Translation-en
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main Translation-en_IN
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main Translation-en
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe Translation-en
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/main Sources
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/restricted Sources
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/universe Sources
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/multiverse Sources
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/main i386 Packages
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/main Translation-en
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/universe Translation-en
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main Translation-en_IN
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/multiverse Translation-en_IN
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/restricted Translation-en_IN
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe Translation-en_IN
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main Translation-en_IN
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/multiverse Translation-en_IN
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/restricted Translation-en_IN
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe Translation-en_IN
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/main Translation-en_IN
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/multiverse Translation-en_IN
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/restricted Translation-en_IN
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/universe Translation-en_IN
W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 11.10 _Oneiric Ocelot_ - Release i386 (20111012)/dists/oneiric/main/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 11.10 _Oneiric Ocelot_ - Release i386 (20111012)/dists/oneiric/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonls/redshift-ppa/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonls/redshift-ppa/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: check `/etc/apt/sources.list` and remove the ppa you where updating from cdrom and the ppa from jonls because it doesn't exists anymmore.

Comment: @mic How to reach to /etc/apt/sources.list and how to edit that list?

Comment: @mic sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list opens few links in terminal. Now what to do? Can you please guide me trough complete steps?

Comment: @mic How to save the file after modification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the GUI to remove the CDROM and PPA that are causing problems

System Settings --> Software Sources --> Other Software (tab)

You can just untick the entries, or <kbd>Remove</kbd> them altogether.