# Why ubuntu software center, synaptic and terminal are not able to download anything?

Tags: 12.04

I am using ubuntu 12.04LTS. From past few days i am not able to update and downlaod anything. The ubuntu software center crash everytime I open it. Synaptic also got the same problem and the terminal show some sort of repository error while downloading and updating ubuntu.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update Manager Ubuntu 12.10 (1) Failed to fetch cdrom: (2) Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonls/](http://askubuntu.com/questions/226979/update-manager-ubuntu-12-10-1-failed-to-fetch-cdrom-2-failed-to-fetch-http)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely a problem with the repositories, such as a PPA being removed and is no longer available.  Have a look at the answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226979/update-manager-ubuntu-12-10-1-failed-to-fetch-cdrom-2-failed-to-fetch-http/226993#226993):

Comment: W: GPG error: http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ precise/partner i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_partner_binary-i386_Packages)
E:Encountered a section with no Package:header
E:Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_partner_i18n_Translation-en
E:The package lists or status file couldn't be parsed or opened